# How to join two tables and select non matching columns

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to write a laravel SQL query to join two tables and extract the non-matching columns from tables.

Products Table

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abe |
| 2 | edfg |
| 3 | swfgd |
| 4 | df |
| 5 | fg |

Clearing Table

| Product_id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | edfg |
| 4 | df |
| 5 | fg |

Now, I'm expecting the result table to be the following.

Result table

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abe |
| 3 | swfgd |

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Show us some syntax so we can reply appropriately. The SQL side is simple enough

Comment: $pro1 = DB::table('products')
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query){
     DB::table('products')
     ->join('clearing_quantity_products', 'clearing_quantity_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
     ->select('products.id');
    })
    ->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create model for each table.

For Products table create model using command

```
php artisan make:model Product
```

This command will create file in `app/Models` and add relationship `hasMany`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="Products";

    public function clearing(){

        return $this->hasMany(Clearing::class,'Product_id','id');
    }
}
```

and same way create model for  Clearing  table

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clearing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="Clearing";
}
```

and in your controller

```
$products=Product::whereDoesntHave('clearing')->get()
```

Comment: Can you please let me know, Where is it wrong?

Comment: @KiritPendyala isnt working means? what exactly the error

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a left anti-join approach here:

```php
$users = DB::table('Products p')
    ->select("p.id", "p.Name")
    ->leftJoin('Clearings c', function($join) {
        $join->on('p.id', '=', 'c.Product_id');
        $join->on('p.Name', '=', 'c.Name');
    })
    ->whereNull('c.Product_id');
    ->get();
```

This would correspond to the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Clearing c
    ON p.id = c.Product_id AND p.Name = c.Name
WHERE
    c.Product_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hey, It is working on but when I'm debugging and found that product.id is returning as null for every record. How can I fix that?

Comment: @KiritPendyala It helps to have a call to `select()`, which I missed, and which was probably causing the problem you are seeing now.

Comment: I get it. How to retrieve all the attributes from the products, Instead of accessing by name individually. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1 from clearing c where c.product_id = p.id);
```

Comment: Can you please help me in writing in laravel PHP Query